# Update Whole Table every 5 minutes

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, optimization, timer

We currently develop a portal in asp.net mvc2 with fluent nhibernate on amazon cloud servers which have lots of user which buying or selling shares. Also they comment every where and make other activities.

Portal is actually behave like multiple portals which we called Community.  Our basic statistics based on users activity (buy,sell, comment etc).  We have a basic structure called TopUsers.  Which we show top user home page for all topics for loggedin community.  On topic page we show top users for current topic etc.

Because of a lot of calculation I want to make a top users table. I am waiting for recommentations for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach (separate table that gets periodically repopulated) is correct, except for the interval: your users will not be fanatically clicking on your site every minute to see updated stats, so after a certain threshold of data there isn't much point in refreshing your top users this often. Doing it once per day will usually be good enough.

Comment: Denis, thank you for your reply. But our system is mainly based on transactions. do you think 24 hours is a reasonable period?

Comment: It's a cache ying/yang question, really. How important it is that your stats are accurate to the second or minute? To you, it might be. To your site's visitors, usually not at all.

Comment: you are right Denis, it is really a cache ying/yang question.  it is important but i agree with you it should not be in second or minutes. Maybe 2 or 4 hours is reasonable. i accept your answer.